# How do I download an msi file via an asp.net button?

Tags: asp.net

So, I've created my wonderful winforms app that I want to unleash upon the world, and now I am trying to create a simple website to host some basic information and link to the setup file (msi installer file )....

I have a button on the asp.net page and the setup file setupApp.msi in same folder as the asp.net page. I am currently trying the following:

```
   Response.Redirect("http://./SetupApp.msi");
```

But this best guess at what to do is not working. Is there something wrong with Mime types here? What do I need to put in the click event to allow users to download this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path you are passing in to the method is not valid (there's no server name called ".").

You can pass in a relative path and it should work fine because ASP.NET will resolve the path:

```
Response.Redirect("SetupApp.msi")
```

Or if it's not in the same folder, try one of these:

```
Response.Redirect("../Downloads/SetupApp.msi")
Response.Redirect("~/SomeFolder/SetupApp.msi")
```

Keep in mind that you don't necessarily have to do the whole redirect at all. Instead of writing code in an ASPX file you could just have a link to your MSI:

```
<a href="SetupApp.msi">Download my app!</a>
```